# Page Inspector: URL must map to a project in the current solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the standard internet application template with ASP.NET MVC 4. When I try to view Login.cshtml via Page Inspector, I get this error:

> Page Inspector: URL must map to a project in the current solution

I don't see why. I don't see a URL that seems to be mapped somewhere else. Why am I getting this error?

This happens even when creating a new project, without modifying any code. Steps to reproduce:

1. File -> New -> Project
2. ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application
3. Choose Internet Application
4. Open Views/Account/Login.cshtml
5. Open Page Inspector (View -> Other Windows -> Page Inspector)
6. Click the Problem button at the top of Page Inspector
7. You should see the error shown above

Comment: What is the actual URL that you are trying to reach?  In MVC, you do not append  the .cshtml to your browser request.  So, for the login page, it should be something like http://localhost/Account/Login

Comment: @Tommy localhost/Account/Login is correct.

Comment: Thanks Bob, do you have any custom routes defined?  Do you have an account controller with a login action?  I hate to ask the basic questions...but, it's a starting point.

Comment: @Tommy No custom routes defined. And yes, there is an account controller with two Login() methods. Perhaps I should create a new project and see if I get the same problem. And no worries about asking the basic questions; sometimes those are the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I just created a new MVC 4 internet app from scratch, didn't modify anything, and the same problem occurs. I'll modify the question to reflect that, so folks don't think the problem was a modification I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. When following the steps to reproduce, in the original question, for some reason the URL in Page Inspector is this:

> file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%2011.0/Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/Web%20Tools/Eureka/en-US/Startup.html

I'm not sure why that happens, but Page Inspector is definitely not showing the Login form.

To get the Login form to show in Page Inspector:

> Right-click anywhere in Login.cshtml, and choose  View in Page
>   Inspector. Voila.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution turned out to be changing the Project properties -> Web -> Override application root URL to -> Unchecked.